# Reading Excel file using poi and storing in multi-dimensional array doesn't bring all the data in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, apache-poi

Hello I am trying to bring data from excel to multi-dimensional array by looping, it brings the data except for the last row. What could be done to fix it please?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    String filePath = "C:\\testXL.xlsx";

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");


    int rows = ws.getLastRowNum(); //will give us how many rows until the last row
    int cols = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

    String[][] rowCol = new String[rows][cols];

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++){

        XSSFRow myRow = ws.getRow(r);

        for (int c = 0; c<cols; c++){

            String value = myRow.getCell(c).toString();

            rowCol[r][c] = value;

            System.out.print(rowCol[r][c]+ "\t");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

it prints upto 4th row and doesn't print the last row

This is the excel file:

[image: excel]

**Edit:**

`int rows = ws.getLastRowNum()+1;`

This seems to solve the issue, if there is any other better way to solve it please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: The Javadoc is ambiguous.  It says it returns _"last row contained on this sheet (0-based) or -1 if no row exists"_ which is not self-consistent. The fact that it returns `-1` and not `0` for no rows implies that you might need to iterate `for (int r = 0; r <= rows; r++)`.  Are you also missing the last column?

Comment: ws.getRow(r) can return null if there are no populated cells on a given row - you should read the javadocs of the methods you are using - I would recommend getting a row iterator for the sheet instead

Comment: and myRow.getCell(c) can return null too.

Comment: @Jim Garrison When i changed it to - `for (int r = 0; r <= rows; r++)`, it doesn't change anything except it now gives me an exception as "Index 4 out of bounds for length 4" along with all the rows except the last one and no i am not missing the last column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int rows = ws.getLastRowNum()+1;`

This seems to solve the issue, if there is any other better way to solve it please let me know.

Thanks